# How can I make viewport content-width=device-width update upon iOS device rotation?

Tags: html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I am developing a page that will only be displayed on iPad, so I don't really need to worry about making it compatible with anything else. I am making a page that I want to be scrollable, but not scalable, and I want it to update the page width without scaling the content.

I tried doing something like this:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width' />
```

That works great, until the device is rotated. The page width does not update to the new width, so the system is pointless. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have two separate stylesheets, one for each orientation (this could also be done in-page if you'd prefer)

In each, you could set the "body { width: ---px; }" to the specific width of the device.

Of course, I have seen other iPad webapps that are scrollable but not scaleable that simply stay the landscape width at all times - you just also have the option to scroll left or right when in portrait mode. In this case you would simply need to define body width as usual for the landscape width of the ipad, which I believe is 1024px.